# 401 Error when consuming an API from Go Code, while cURL Works well

Tags: rest, api, http, go, curl

I've written a simple go code that, sends a GET request to an API and in response I receive a 401 error. However when I use cURL, I receive the desired response. I also get expected response using [API Tester](https://apitester.com). So, I believe, there has to be something wrong with my code and that, I'm unable to find out.

Below is my Go code, that, responds with 401 Error

```
func main() {
    clusterId := os.Getenv("CLUSTER_ID")
    apiUrl := "https://api.qubole.com/api/v1.3/clusters/"+clusterId+"/state"
    auth_token := os.Getenv("X_AUTH_TOKEN")
    fmt.Println("URL - ",apiUrl)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", apiUrl, nil)
    if(err != nil){
        fmt.Println("ERROR in getting rest response",err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("X-Auth-Token", auth_token)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")

    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if(err != nil){
       fmt.Println("Error: No response received", err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    //print raw response body for debugging purposes
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

Extract of Response/Error I get, is as follows:

```
URL -  https://api.qubole.com/api/v1.3/clusters/presto-bi/state
{"error":{"error_code":401,"error_message":"Invalid Token"}}
```

Now, Following is the cURL command that, returns me the desired response

```
curl -X GET -H "X-AUTH-TOKEN:$X_AUTH_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" "https://us.qubole.com/api/v1.3/clusters/presto-bi/state"
```

below is the stdout I receive, which is as expected: `{"state":"DOWN"}%`

Comment: I think you need print apiUrl for debug this error.

Comment: Are you just missing the `clusters` path in your URL? e.g. `apiUrl := "https://api.qubole.com/api/v1.3/clusters/"+clusterId+"/state"`

Comment: @ssemilla - Thanks for pointing that out, I just corrected it and still getting the error. This time 401 tho. However, not sure why? as the token is same as used with Curl. (an env variable - as you can see) I've just edited my question.

Comment: why hostname in go code is "api.qubole.com" while in curl command is "us.qubole.com"?

Comment: Thank you. That, was the error- a stupid one though. That is because, the documentation of API provider states it WRONG (https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/rest-api/cluster_api/start-terminate-cluster.html) . But, since I login using us.qubole.com, I used that, when I was writing my cURL command

Comment: @KibGzr Can you please post your answer, I'll accept it and that, would be the closure.

Comment: Whoever has downvoted the question. Please explain the reason for your downvote as that, would help me ask a better and improved question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need check api hostname at golang and curl again. Thanks!

The error is because, the documentation of API provider states the host WRONG ([API Documentation](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/rest-api/cluster_api/start-terminate-cluster.html)) . But, since the portal login is us.qubole.com ([PORTAL Login URL](https://us.qubole.com/home)), cURL command was written considering that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here without enough information. I'm assuming `clusterId := os.Getenv("CLUSTER_ID")` is `presto-bi`. If that is the case, then you are just missing "clusters" in your path.

```
apiUrl := "https://api.qubole.com/api/v1.3/clusters/"+clusterId+"/state"
```

Also, shouldn't you use `us.qubole.com/api` instead of `api.qubole.com`?